# Unable to Install Cockpit on Bionic

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dependencies, update-manager

I am trying to install cockpitvby using `apt-get install cockpit` but getting following error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
cockpit : Depends: cockpit-system (= 172-1~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed 
          Recommends: cockpit-storaged (= 172-1~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

With little bit of googling  and cockpit [instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports#Enabling_Backports) from Ubuntu,I also added following line to `source.list`

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

as outlined in [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports#Enabling_Backports), then updated

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try installing

```
sudo apt-get install cockpit
```

But still getting following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cockpit : Depends: cockpit-system (= 172-1~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: cockpit-storaged (= 172-1~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt install -f` to dependencies?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, No just tried sudo apt-get install cockpit. Shall I try , sudo apt-get install cockpit -f ? '

Comment: I said `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, Just did run sudo apt install -f,  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: ok run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Done, command executes but there is no output

Comment: run this again `sudo apt install -f  && sudo apt install cockpit`

Comment: Done, getting same error message (in question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81863/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-simsons).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that cockpit exists in the official repository of Bionic so to install simply do:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install cockpit
```

Note: Remove those repos you added and the update via `sudo apt update` and proceed to install.

After due interaction with OP I discovered that the problem was he lacked the `universe` repos in `sources.list` so to overcome we followed these steps:

1. Add repo:

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository universe
   ```
2. update accordingly:

   ```
    sudo apt update
   ```
3. Now install:

   ```
    sudo apt install cockpit
   ```

Comment: this saved my day :)